# How to unittest a class using RestTemplate offline?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, junit, resttemplate

I have a class which has direct dependency on the RestTemplate. I wish I have a JUnit test of it, offline.

How could I mock a RestTemplate in my unittest?

Comment: Check out my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22334918/1077708

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I suggest refactoring your client code to *remove* the direct dependency on `RestTemplate`, and replace it with references to `RestOperations`, which is the interface implemented by `RestTemplate`. and the one you should be coding to.

You can then inject a stub or mock of `RestOperations` into your code for unit testing, and inject a `RestTemplate` when using it for real.

Comment: What Mr @skaffman said is generally true and correct. However, I must point out that `RestTemplate` is used pretty much EVERYWHERE google will take you, even `MockRestServiceServer` (as pointed out by @Raedwald). In addition, Javadoc for `RestOperations` state _Not often used directly, but a useful option to enhance testability, as it can easily be mocked or stubbed._

Comment: A follow up question: if you do use `RestOperations`, and the instance is consumed by a `Service` implementation (class under test), how would you get the mocked `RestOperations` instance into the service? Instantiate the service directly in the test, and use a setter?

Comment: It is very easy to mock a `RestTemplate` these days, but quite difficult to implement all of `RestOperations` many methods.

Answer (score 35):

Sping 3.0 introduced `RestTemplate`. Since version 3.2, the [Spring MVC test framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework) has provided the class [`MockRestServiceServer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html) for unit testing client REST code.

Comment: Is it available on Android?

Comment: @Piotr, This is working for me with gradle: androidTestCompile("org.springframework:spring-test:3.2.8.RELEASE") {
        exclude module: "spring-core"
    }

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Mock classes in package [`org.springframework.mock.web`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/mock/web/package-summary.html).

Usually you will need [`MockHttpServletRequest`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html) and [`MockHttpServletResponse`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletResponse.html), but if you need more control you may also need others, e.g. [`MockRequestDispatcher`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockRequestDispatcher.html).

Both of these implement the corresponding Servlet interfaces but add convenience methods for testing (and, most importantly: they work without a real HTTP connection).

You can find the Mock classes in the spring-test jar ([accessible through Maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test/3.0.5.RELEASE))

---

**Update:** it seems that the above classes are no great help for `RestTemplate` after all. What you will need is to create a mock [`ClientHttpRequestFactory`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestFactory.html), and I'm surprised to see that there isn't one in the above package. Here is some code to get you started (haven't tested it):

```
public class MockClientHttpRequestFactory implements
    ClientHttpRequestFactory{

    // overwrite this if you want
    protected MockClientHttpResponse createResponse(){
        return new MockClientHttpResponse();
    }

    // or this
    protected HttpStatus getHttpStatusCode(){
        return HttpStatus.OK;
    }

    // or even this
    @Override
    public ClientHttpRequest createRequest(final URI uri,
        final HttpMethod httpMethod) throws IOException{
        return new MockClientHttpRequest(uri, httpMethod);
    }

    public class MockClientHttpResponse implements ClientHttpResponse{
        private final byte[] data = new byte[10000];
        private final InputStream body = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        private final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        private HttpStatus status;

        @Override
        public InputStream getBody() throws IOException{
            return body;
        }

        @Override
        public HttpHeaders getHeaders(){
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        public HttpStatus getStatusCode() throws IOException{
            return getHttpStatusCode();
        }

        @Override
        public String getStatusText() throws IOException{
            return status.name();
        }

        @Override
        public void close(){
            try{
                body.close();
            } catch(final IOException e){
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }

        }

    }

    class MockClientHttpRequest implements ClientHttpRequest{

        private final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        private final HttpMethod method;
        private final URI uri;
        private final OutputStream body = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        MockClientHttpRequest(final URI uri, final HttpMethod httpMethod){
            this.uri = uri;
            method = httpMethod;

        }

        @Override
        public OutputStream getBody() throws IOException{
            return body;
        }

        @Override
        public HttpHeaders getHeaders(){
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        public HttpMethod getMethod(){
            return method;
        }

        @Override
        public URI getURI(){
            return uri;
        }

        @Override
        public ClientHttpResponse execute() throws IOException{
            return createResponse();
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: You did not answer my question. Your solution do help on the test of the server side servlet, MVC framework. I am going to test the client side, who use the MVC framework.

Comment: This is just what I was after for one of my REST projects. Thanks very much.

Comment: (+1) the idea works. But I have the feeling, that the two methods `getStatusCode` and `getStatusText` in `MockClientHttpResponse` suffering a bit from Schizophrenia. May `getStatusText(){return this.getStatusCode().name();}` would heal them. ;-)

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd I also have similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698072/simpleclienthttprequestfactory-vs-httpcomponentsclienthttprequestfactory-for-htt) which uses RestTemplate, see if you can help me out if possible. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

[spring-social-test](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social) contains mockup classes that help write tests for `RestTemplate`. There are also some examples on how to use it within the git repository (e.g. [OAuth1TemplateTest](http://git.springsource.org/spring-social/spring-social/blobs/master/spring-social-test/src/test/java/org/springframework/social/oauth1/OAuth1TemplateTest.java)).

Please keep in mind that there's currently a Spring feature request ([#SPR-7951](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7951)) to move these classes to spring-web.

Comment: This is ***very*** useful for testing rest clients.