# SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory vs HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory for Http Request timeout with RestTemplate?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, httprequest, resttemplate

I am working on a project in which I need to make a HTTP URL call to my server which is running Restful Service which returns back the response as a `JSON String`.

Below is my main code which is using the future and callables:

```
public class TimeoutThreadExample {

    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public String getData() {
        Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Task(restTemplate));
        String response = null;

        try {
            response = future.get(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Below is my `Task` class which implements the `Callable` interface and uses the `RestTemplate`:

```
class Task implements Callable<String> {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public Task(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    public String call() throws Exception {

        String url = "some_url";
        String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);

        return response;
    }
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

As you can see above, I am using default way of executing the URL using `RestTemplate` which doesn't use any Http Request timeout so that means internally it is using `-1` as the `read` and `connection` timeout.

Now what I am looking to do is, I want to set up Http Request timeout using `RestTemplate` in my above code efficiently. And I am not sure which class I need to use for that, I can see `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` and `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` so not sure which one I need to use?

Any simple example basis on my above code will help me understand better on how to set the Http Request timeout using `RestTemplate`.

And also does my Http Request timeout value should be less than future timeout value?

- `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` vs `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory`. Which one to use?
- Does my Http Request timeout value should be less than future timeout value?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default RestTemplate uses `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` which depends on default configuration of `HttpURLConnection`.

You can configure them by using below attributes:

```
-Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=TimeoutInMiliSec 
-Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=TimeoutInMiliSec
```

If you want to use `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` -  it has a connection pooling configuration which `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` does not have.

A sample code for using `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`:

```
public class TimeoutThreadExample {

    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    private static final RestTemplate restTemplate = createRestTemplate();

    private static RestTemplate createRestTemplate(){
       HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
       requestFactory.setReadTimeout(READ_TIME_OUT);
       requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIME_OUT);
       return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
     }

    public String getData() {
        Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Task(restTemplate));
        String response = null;

        try {
            response = future.get(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. By any chance do you know which one we are suppose to use? Or we can use any one of those two? And also how would I use `requestFactory` in my above code base efficiently? I understand from your example how to use it but where do I fit `requestFactory` in my above code base since I am using DI to pass the RestTemplate.

Comment: It is up to you, but personally in our large scale projects we have used HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory. But I guess there should not be any problem with both approaches. With `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` you can configure more options using your own `HttpClient`. 
For using in your codebase, just pass the `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` instance like the code I wrote at the end of my answer

Comment: Sure, I am thinking of using `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`. I didn't understand which instance you want me to pass? If  you can provide an example basis on my code base then I would understand better what do you mean by that?

Comment: Please see the updated answer, you need to create a singleton shared instance of `RestTemplate` since its thread-safe and heavy to be created. PS: I've not tested the code.

Comment: Thanks for edit. Now I understand clearly what you meant earlier. One last question, what is the difference between `READ Timeout` vs `Connection Timeout` here?

Comment: connection timeout is about initial connection handshake, read timeout is = if you block the response in the middle of processing the response. ReadTimout is here - https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/params/HttpConnectionParams.html#getSoTimeout()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60767/discussion-between-akiweb-and-jama-jurayevich).

Comment: I'm using `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` after I got issue with `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` while extracting the 401 exception response body. Below is my sample code, I'm using defaults with `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` and no custom configurations like timeout and custom custom `HTTPClient`

    `@Bean public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
            RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
            template.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
            return template;
 }`

Answer (score 1):

SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory uses the standard JDK's HTTP library, and hence does not support methods like `HttpMethod.PATCH`. So it's better to use `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` now than change it later when you have to.